# Copy constructor error when initilizing a vector of custormer typed objects

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, copy-constructor

Class `Foo` only has a default constructor and a copy constructor. A vector of size 10 initialized by object of type `Foo` is somehow incorrect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() = default; // Error1
        Foo(Foo& foo) {  // Error2
            std::cout << "copied" << std::endl;
        }

};

int main( void )
{
    Foo f;
    std::vector<Foo> vec(10, f); // Error3
    return 0;
}
```

There are 3 errors for the sample code above:

**Error1:** candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided

**Error2:** candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const Foo') would lose const qualifier

**Error3:** in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector >::vector' requested here

When I remove the copy constructor or the vector in the main function, there are no errors.

**Question:**

Which part of the code is wrong and why?

p.s.

When the vector definition is replaced by `Foo ff(f)`, errors are gone as well. Is the `const` qualifier is request by the vector?

Comment: A copy constructor that modifies the thing it copies from looks strange.

Comment: Read the second error carefully.

Comment: Try making the copy constructor `Foo(const Foo& foo)`

Comment: @Detonar Yes, code is compiled after adding `const` qualifier.  But is this a request from vector? Since `Foo ff(f)` works fine without the `const` qualifier.

Comment: @SLN I guess `std::vector` adds `const` before copying to ensure the initial object is not changed in some weird copy constructors like the ones juanchopanza had in mind while posting his comment.

Comment: @SLN - Think of it like this. If I gave you my lecture to notes to copy after you missed a class, it'd be pretty poor form to doodle all over my notebook, won't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the signature of the invoked constructor of `std::vector`:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The argument `f` is passed by const reference (parameter `value`). That parameter therefore cannot be bound to non-const parameter `foo` of type `Foo&` of `Foo`'s copy constructor.

---

Same (simpler) case:

```
Foo f;
const Foo& value = f;
Foo& foo = value;  // error
```

Comment: @bolov - Sorry what? You can't bind a **non-const** reference to an object that is const or is referred to by a const reference. This answer is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you use is [std::vector::vector (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

> ```
> vector( size_type count, 
>                  const T& value,
>                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
> ```

The parameter `value` which will be copied inside the constructor is const, and because your copy constructor cannot copy from const the implementation of the constructor cannot create copies to fill the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor documentation of [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) shows the following signature:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

This shows that it requires `val` to be a `const` reference. Because it most likely won't cut this `const` in it's internal processing it seems to pass `val` like this to the copy constructor. Because Foo's copy constructor expects an non-`const` reference to be passed `val` would lose it's `const` qualifier. Because this is not allowed the compiler raises the error

> Error: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const Foo') would lose const qualifier